# Cannot declare dynamic buttons in existing code

Tags: android

When I declare a gridview in the class below, I get a range of errors.

```
class LoadAllProducts extends Activity //get call on dynamic btn action 
{
    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("I have enterd in external class");
        // ***GridView gridView3 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview3);***//cant declare getting error  
        ArrayList mButtons3 = new ArrayList(); //to print button dynamically on gridview 
        Button cb3; //=new Button(this); if do so getting error 
        JSONObject json2 = null;
        json2 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        //  System.out.println("success to get json object for all products/t"+json2);// getting data from php an mysql database   

        JSONArray products2 = null;
        String[] Itemname = null;
        String[] rcatacode = null;
        try {
            int success2 = json2.getInt(TAG_ALLPRODUCT_SUCCESS);
            products2 = json2.getJSONArray(TAG_ALLPRODUCT_PRODUCTS);

            Itemname = new String[products2.length()];
            rcatacode = new String[products2.length()];
            if (success2 == 1) {
                cb3 = new Button(this);
                for (int i = 0; i < products2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products2.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable 
                    String itemcode = c.getString(TAG_ALLPRODUCT_MCODE); //to store data from database 
                    String itemname = c.getString(TAG_ALLPRODUCT_ITEM_NAME);
                    String item_rate = c.getString(TAG_ALLPRODUCT_RATE);
                    String r_cata = c.getString(TAG_ALLPRODUCT_RCATA);
                    Itemname[i] = itemname;
                    rcatacode[i] = r_cata;

                }
            }
        } // try closed 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            // Button b=new Button(this); //getting error on here also 

            System.out.println(Itemname[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. don't add `<p>` at each line of your code - 2. don't just write a title and put code in the body - 3. format your code correctly - 4. try to explain what you try and what doesn't work and what possible error messages you have.

Comment: Abhijeet, your question is valid, that saved you. Next time please format your question neatly. Upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even know where to start...

1. you extend `Activity` but your `onCreate()` is missing the `Bundle` parameter
2. you don't call `super.onCreate()`
3. `ArrayList mButtons3 = new ArrayList();` will not work. `ArrayList` needs a type, something like `ArrayList<Button> mButtons3 = new ArrayList<Button>();`
4. you never call `setContentView()` meaning your activity will never show something

This is just for the first lines of code... are you sure you know the basics about Android development?

Comment: Point 1,2,4 are done in main public void oncreate bundle(saved ins..) class....
Point 3 was a bit usefull...

Comment: And what do you learn about that? Right: Provide all important information and 1, 2 and 4 are really important information for your kind of question... How should any of us see that have overriden the onCreate() method?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you call setContentView which defines the layout this Activity will create, you cannot call findViewById. Think about it, where are you picking up the gridview from ? Which layout ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was been sort out by declaring dynamic buttons outside the `try-catch` block...
the declaration of Button, `TextView`, `EditText`.. etc cannot be done in `try-catch`, `instance.setOnclickLisner(new Onclick..){}` instead it can be done by calling a function for task